# Convert sdf file to urdf.xacro

Tags: ros, urdf, sdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there I actually have a sdf file given and would like to convert it to an urdf.xacro file. As I have not found any converter for that I would like to do that by hand. Now what I currently have is e.g a sdf file which has a content like this:

```
    <joint name='body_link_JOINT_0' type='revolute'>
  <parent>body_link</parent>
  <child>wheel1_link</child>
  <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    <use_parent_model_frame>0</use_parent_model_frame>
    <limit>
      <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>
      <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>
      <effort>-1</effort>
      <velocity>-1</velocity>
    </limit>
    <dynamics>
      <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
      <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
      <damping>0</damping>
      <friction>0</friction>
    </dynamics>
  </axis>
  <physics>
    <ode>
      <limit>
        <cfm>0</cfm>
        <erp>0.2</erp>
      </limit>
      <suspension>
        <cfm>0</cfm>
        <erp>0.2</erp>
      </suspension>
    </ode>
  </physics>
</joint>
```

My current urdf.xacro file looks like this:

```
    <joint name="wheel1_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="base_link" />
  <child link="wheel1_link" />
  <origin xyz="-0.1315 -0.0759 0.2817" rpy="0.9804 -0.3972 -1.5708" />
  <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
  <limit lower="-1.79769e+308" upper="1.79769e+308" effort="-1" velocity="-1" />
  <dynamics friction="0" />
</joint>
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to deal with the physics tag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274885/convert-sdf-file-to-urdf.xacro/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no physics tag defined in URDF. If you add the tag it will be safely ignored.

If you want to pass physics data to Gazebo for simulations you can add gazebo tags to your URDF files as mentioned here: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2017-11-13**:
Hey thanks for your response. I now added gazebo references. According to http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf under " Elements For Links" there is only a limited list which describes attributes I can set. However I do not know if I can use multiple physics engines there as well?!

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-13**:
Not that I've found. You can try asking on the Gazebo forums: http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/